# How to simplify this code and make it into functions?

Tags: c, function, simplify

I am just beginning to code, and I'm trying to recreate the Monty Hall Problem game show. My program gives the user a choice between game mode, research mode, and exiting the game. I'm trying to simplify my code and put game mode and research mode into functions, but all of the research I'm doing isn't really making much sense to me. I would appreciate some help, thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int winning (int win);
float PERCENTAGE (float win,float playedgames);
int RANDOM ();


int main (void)
{
int choice, choice2, Ngames, Ngames2,chosendoor,chosendoor2;
int gamesplayed,gamesplayed2,winningdoor,winningdoor2,revealeddoor;
int switcheddoor, revealeddoor2,stayeddoor, doorchoice,winningdoor3;
int revealeddoor3, choice3, switcheddoor2;
float percent,percent2;
float win = 0,win2 = 0;
int gamesplayed3 = 0,win3 = 0;


srand(time(NULL)); //randomizes based on time


while (choice!=3)
{
    printf ("Please enter one of the following options\n\n1. Research mode\n2. Game mode\n3. Exit\n\n");
    scanf ("%d", &choice);


    switch(choice)
    {
    case 1:
        printf ("\nYou have chosen research mode.\n");
        printf ("Please indicate whether you will always us the always-    switch strategy or the never-switch strategy.\n");
        printf ("1. Always switch doors\n2. Never switch doors\n\n");
        scanf ("%d", &choice2);


        switch (choice2)
        {
        case 1:
            printf ("\nYou have chosen to always switch doors.\n");
            printf ("How many games would you like to play?\n\n");
            scanf ("%d", &Ngames);


            for (gamesplayed = 0;gamesplayed <= Ngames;gamesplayed++)
            {
                winningdoor = RANDOM();
                chosendoor = 1;


                do
                {
                    revealeddoor = RANDOM();
                } while (revealeddoor == chosendoor || revealeddoor == winningdoor);


                do
                {
                    switcheddoor = RANDOM();
                } while (switcheddoor == chosendoor || switcheddoor == revealeddoor);


                if (switcheddoor == winningdoor)
                {
                    win = winning(win);
                }
            }


            percent = PERCENTAGE(win,gamesplayed);


            printf ("\nYou have chosen the winning door %f percent of the time.\n\n", percent);


            win = 0;
            break;


        case 2:
            printf ("\nYou have chosen to never switch doors.\n");
            printf ("How many games would you like to play?\n\n");
            scanf ("%d", &Ngames2);


            for (gamesplayed2 = 0;gamesplayed2 <= Ngames2; gamesplayed2++)
            {
                winningdoor2 = RANDOM();
                chosendoor2 = 1;


                do
                {
                    revealeddoor2 = RANDOM();
                } while (revealeddoor2 == winningdoor2 || revealeddoor2 == chosendoor2);


                do
                {
                    stayeddoor = RANDOM();
                } while (stayeddoor != chosendoor2);


                if (stayeddoor == winningdoor2)
                {
                    win2 = winning(win2);
                }
            }


            percent2 = PERCENTAGE(win2,gamesplayed2);


            printf ("\nYou chose the winning door %f percent of the time.\n\n", percent2);


            win2 = 0;
            break;


        default:
            printf ("You have entered an incorrect value.");
            break;
        }
        break;


    case 2:
        printf ("\nYou have chosen game mode.\n");


        winningdoor3 = RANDOM();


        printf ("Which door will you choose? (Door 1,2, or 3)\n\n");
        scanf ("%d", &doorchoice);


        if (doorchoice < 1 || doorchoice > 3)
        {
            printf ("That value is not a door.\n\n");
            break;
        }


        do
        {
            revealeddoor3 = RANDOM();
        } while  (revealeddoor3 == doorchoice);


        printf ("\nDoor %d was opened and there was no prize behind it.\n", revealeddoor3);
        printf ("Would you like to:\n1. Switch doors?\n2. Stay with your current door?\n\n");
        scanf ("%d", &choice3);


        switch (choice3)
        {
        case 1:
            printf ("\nYou have chosen to switch doors.\n\n");


            do
            {
                switcheddoor2 = rand()%2 + 1;
            } while (switcheddoor2 == doorchoice);


            if (switcheddoor2 == winningdoor3)
            {
                printf ("Good choice! You have won!\n\n");
                win3 = winning(win3);
            }


            else
            {
                printf ("Unfortunately, you lost.\n\n");
            }


            ++gamesplayed3;


            printf ("You have played a total of %d games and you won a total of %d games.\n", gamesplayed3, win3);
            break;


        case 2:
            printf ("\nYou have decided to stay with your current door.\n");


            if (doorchoice == winningdoor3)
            {
                printf ("Good choice! You have won!\n\n");
                win3 = winning(win3);
            }


            else
            {
                printf ("Unfortunately, you lost.\n\n");
            }


            gamesplayed3 = gamesplayed3 + 1;


            printf ("You have played a total of %d games and you won a total of %d games.\n\n", gamesplayed3, win3);
            break;


        default:
            printf ("You have entered an incorrect value.\n\n");
            break;
        }
        break;


        case 3:
            printf("Thanks for playing!");
            exit(0);


        default:
            printf ("You have entered an incorrect value.\n\n");
            break;
    }
}
return 0;
}


int winning (int win)
{
int newwin;
newwin = win + 1;
return (newwin);
}


float PERCENTAGE (float win,float playedgames)
{
float percentage;
percentage = (win/playedgames)*100;
return (percentage);
}


int RANDOM ()
{
int random;
random = rand()%3;
return (random);
}
```

Comment: This code is really unreadable... atleast move the loops inside the cases to a function. Also specify what exactly is the issue concisely and precisely.

Comment: I'm really new at this, and still learning. Would you be able to show me a sample of one of my loops as a function? I'm not sure how to.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example, to convert one of your switch cases...

**Here is your code**

```
case 1:
    printf ("\nYou have chosen to always switch doors.\n");
    printf ("How many games would you like to play?\n\n");
    scanf ("%d", &Ngames);
    for (gamesplayed = 0; gamesplayed <= Ngames; gamesplayed++)
    {
        winningdoor = RANDOM();
        chosendoor = 1;
        do
        {
            revealeddoor = RANDOM();
        }
        while (revealeddoor == chosendoor || revealeddoor == winningdoor);
        do
        {
            switcheddoor = RANDOM();
        }
        while (switcheddoor == chosendoor || switcheddoor == revealeddoor);
        if (switcheddoor == winningdoor)
        {
            win = winning(win);
        }
    }
    percent = PERCENTAGE(win, gamesplayed);
    printf ("\nYou have chosen the winning door %f percent of the time.\n\n", percent);

    win = 0;
    break;
```

**Here is how the same looks after the function is extracted**

```
case 1:
    printf ("\nYou have chosen to always switch doors.\n");
    printf ("How many games would you like to play?\n\n");
    scanf ("%d", &Ngames);
    percent = PERCENTAGE(win, kernel(Ngames));
    printf ("\nYou have chosen the winning door %f percent of the time.\n\n", percent);
    win = 0;
    break;
```

**Here is how the function looks like**

```
int kernel (int Ngames)
{
    int gamesplayed;
    for (gamesplayed = 0; gamesplayed <= Ngames; gamesplayed++)
    {
        int winningdoor = RANDOM();
        int chosendoor = 1;
        int revealeddoor,switcheddoor;
        do
        {
            revealeddoor = RANDOM();
        }
        while (revealeddoor == chosendoor || revealeddoor == winningdoor);
        do
        {
            switcheddoor = RANDOM();
        }
        while (switcheddoor == chosendoor || switcheddoor == revealeddoor);
        if (switcheddoor == winningdoor)
        {
            win = winning(win);
        }
    }
    return gamesplayed;
}
```

Now when you look at the particular switch case, you can understand its meaning much better. Only if you need to know the logic of kernel you have to go inside.

I would say that, if you are computing something which has a real meaning move it out as a function. If you reuse some code, make it a function. If your function is long or have too much loop (while, for) or conditional nesting (if, switch) then it is time to modularize your code.